# Need to stack specific columns and leave the others unchanged

Tags: python, pandas, stack

I want to stack column B and C and leave the other columns as is.

This is what I have

```
    A      B     C   D
0  a1  hello1   bye1  d1
1  a2  hello2   bye2  d2
2  a3  hello3   bye3  d3
3  a4  hello4   bye4  d4
```

I've tried using the melt and stack functions. Can't get what I want.

This is what I want

```
    A      B     C   D
0  a1  hello1        d1
1  a2  hello2        d2
2  a3  hello3        d3
3  a4  hello4        d4
4       bye1
5       bye2
6       bye3
7       bye4
```

Comment: The first concern is: what would go in the first and third and fourth columns where you show them empty? It would have to be `pd.NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data={"A":['a1','a2','a3','a4'],
                      "B":["hello1","hello2","hello3","hello4"],
                      "C":["bye1","bye2","bye3","bye4"],
                      "D":["d1","d2","d3","d4"]})

df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df['C'].values,columns=['B'])],sort=False,ignore_index=True)
df['C'] = ''
df.fillna('',inplace=True)
```

```
     A    B     C    D
0   a1  hello1      d1
1   a2  hello2      d2
2   a3  hello3      d3
3   a4  hello4      d4
4       bye1        
5       bye2        
6       bye3        
7       bye4
```

## in addition to your question

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'B': df['C'].values,'A': df['D'].values})
final_res = pd.concat([df,res],sort=False,ignore_index=True)
final_res[['C','D']]=''
print(final_res)
```

```
A       B      C  D
0  a1  hello1    
1  a2  hello2    
2  a3  hello3    
3  a4  hello4    
4  d1    bye1    
5  d2    bye2    
6  d3    bye3    
7  d4    bye4
```

Comment: how could i add more to the concat function like if I want column A and D stacked also? I'll drop column C and D after.

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez i have updated the answer you can check it

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a possible solution (although, there may be a more efficient method)**

- Setup initial DF

`df = pd.DataFrame([["a1", "Hello1","bye1", "d1"], ["a2", "Hello2","bye2", "d2"], ["a3", "Hello3","bye3", "d3"]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])`

- Make copy of original DF

`df2 = df.copy()`

- Reorder/Remove all columns except desired column

`df2["A"] = ""`

`df2["B"] = df2["C"]`

`df2["C"] = ""`

`df2["D"] = ""`

- Concatenate original DF with the altered DF.

`result = pd.concat([df, df2])`

`result["C"] = ""` - remove the entries in col "C".

[image: results df]

Answer (score 1):

Trying another way:

```
cols=['B','C']
final=(df.reindex(range(df.shape[0]*len(cols)))
         .assign(B=df.melt(df.columns^cols).value,C=np.nan).fillna(''))
```

---

```
    A       B  C   D
0  a1  hello1     d1
1  a2  hello2     d2
2  a3  hello3     d3
3  a4  hello4     d4
4        bye1      
5        bye2      
6        bye3      
7        bye4
```